# How do I open MULTIPLE web urls by clicking a single Google Extension I've created?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I searched the web in the hopes of finding a way to create google chrome extensions that show up in the "App" area when I load Chrome. These extension were meant to be to simply open a pre-defined webpage when clicked... in essence, a bookmark in the "App" area. I have been successful creating multiple shortcuts for pages I use quite frequently... here is an example of a ' manifest.json ' file I used for a shortcut to my local CraigsList site...

---

```
{
"name": "CraigsList",
"description": "shop on craigslist",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
"128": "icon.jpeg"
},
"app": {
"urls": [
"http://COSprings.craigslist.org"
],
"launch": {
"web_url": "http://COSprings.craigslist.org"
}
},
"permissions": [
"unlimitedStorage",
"notifications"
]
}
```

---

I'm very happy that i've come this far and created a host of shortcuts that have simplified my life in Google Chrome... but I'd like to take it a step further with one more extension.

Let's say I wanted to open TWO tabs... each with a different webpage when the extension is clicked... how would I modify the above code to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome extensions are powerful, but your approach is wrong. If you really wanted to open multple tabs by clicking on the app icon, then the linked page has to open these tabs themselves, because a maximum of one tab/panel can be launched on initialisation.

In Chrome 22+, you can use [`chrome.experimental.app.onLaunched`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.app.html#event-onLaunched) to detect the launch of the app, and then use [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) to launch multiple tabs...

**But this method is too convoluted for your goal**! Don't re-invent the wheel, Chrome already offers something which suits your needs. It's called **bookmark bar**:

[image: Chromium's bookmark bar]

As you can see, I've bookmarked some images and folders.
You probably knows that clicking on a bookmark opens a single page.
The following feature might surprise you: Right-click on a bookmark folder.

[image: Contextmenu]

Use `Open All Bookmarks` or `Open All Bookmarks in New Window` to open multiple bookmarks at once (obviously, the bookmarks have to be an item in the bookmarks folder).

Comment: Advanced web users snub Favorites and Bookmarks so much that we forget how useful they can be.  I spent a lot of time looking for a solution in the Chrome Web Store before finding this thread!  The only issue with this solution is having to press Ctrl Shift B every time to make the Booksmarks bar visible and then hide it again.

Comment: @KnocksX Just open a new tab, and the bookmarks bar will be visible, as seen in my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it directly from the manifest (which I think isn't possible), you could use a background script.
Put something like this in your manifest:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

Then in the `background.js` file:

```
var queue = ['www.url1.com', 'www.url2.com'];
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    for (var i=0; i<queue[1].length; ++i)
        chrome.tabs.create({"url": queue[i], "active": false, "index": tab.index+i});
});
```